# Multi Thread in Python run in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a question about multithread in Python.

I already tried Multithread and MultiProcessing in python.

What I get is
in MultiThread, I will get a duplicate result when run it pararelly. After research, I found that in the multiThread, the Multithread can update the same variable(race Condition).

Meanwhile, in the multi processing, it will go smoothly, without problem like in the Multithread.

The question,
Can I use Multithread, but the mechanism is like Multiprocessing? Because I need to migrate more than 2 million record, and I need to run that function asynchronously as much as possible (My laptop only have 4 cores) that's why I need to use multiThread.

Can some explain to me about the question above?

Answer (score 1):

In multithreading, each **thread** will share the same memory space as the parent process that spawned them. But in multi-processing, each **process** have their own memory space.

However, in multithreading, you need to use a lock (semaphore/mutex), (e.g. [`threading.Lock()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to prevent the race condition. It is not to say that multiprocessing will not have race condition, it can have it if you specifically share the same object and not the copy of it. But by default it will copy the object.

Multithreading is also limited by python's GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which ensures that only one thread is running at the same time. So if you have intensive computation task running on two threads, it doesn't really make it faster, as only one can be active at the same time.

However, multiprocessing can overcome it easily, as it runs on multiple process and each process will be handled by OS's scheduler and run parallely.

General rule of thumb:
if your process is computationally intensive, use process
if your process is I/O intensive, use threads

If your thread needs concurrent access to the same var/object, etc, you need to use lock.

Comment: Do you mean multi-processing in 2nd line??

Comment: @AhmadAnis good catch, thanks. Fixed the typo.